# label boxplot extreme points in julia using Plotly Backend

Tags: julia, plotly, boxplot, interactive, plots.jl

i'm plotting a boxplot using plotlyJS backend for Plots in Julia 0.6.2

And i'm trying to make it possible to show particular labels (strings) for the points that are extreme. (so we can identify them easily).

check the image for further details
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzbO7.png)

code:

`using Plots
plotlyjs()
boxplot(data_mat,ylabel="measure", xlabel="categs", title = "data")`

i have a specific label for each point. and these labels are the same for the 17 conditions.

thanx

Comment: A minimal working example for generating the plot (without labels) would be nice.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to set the hover property for those points, I am assuming you checked this property in Plots.jl already. BTW, on a related topic, I started a package yesterday called [ExtremeStats.jl](https://github.com/juliohm/ExtremeStats.jl) for modeling extremes if you are interested, I will be adding plot recipes as time allows.

Comment: Yead that's true. the feature doesn't exist for the moment.
With Plotly backend, it is possible to point extremes on a boxplot but you get only some principal quantile values and not the point specific value.

Comment: @crstnbr the code example is quite simple that why i didnt post it:
`plotlyjs()
    boxplot(data_mat,ylabel="measure",
                    xlabel="categs",
                    title = "data")`